# How to send blade from data to python script and return the result from that script to view using laravel?

Tags: javascript, python, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

I have a machine learning algorithm written in python. What I want right now is to send form data to that python script from my blade file. And recieve the processed data  output from the python script and show on the view file.

here is the input function on my python script

```
def readSequence(Sequence):
        sequence = Sequence          
        print(sequence)
```

And here is the output:

```
if final_pred == 0 :
    print("Not Found")

if final_pred == 1 :
    print("Foundd")
```

Comment: You might want to turn your Python script into a microservice which receives POST/GET requests from your Laravel instance. I'd recommend using [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You may use API method to communicate both of the platform. Guzzle is a good case to handle both of it.

Laravel side will request the API from Python, then the request result you can display from the Laravel Blade.